# compact subset and proof

Tags: continuity, compactness

$X$ be a compact subset of $\mathbb{R}$ and let $f$ be a real-valued function on $X$. Prove that $f$ is continuous if and only if $\{(x,f(x)) : x ∈ X\} $ is compact subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$.

how should we start to proof?

Comment: First show that if $f$ is continuous, its graph is compact. For the other direction use that the projection is a continuous bijection between the graph and $X$.

Comment: You need to use backslashes to get the curly braces: `\{` and $`\}`.

Answer (score 1):

Since we are talking about $\Bbb R$, one preferred way is to work with *sequences*. $X\subseteq\Bbb R$ is compact iff all sequences of $X$ has convergent subsequence with limit point in $X$.

Similarly, $f$ is continuous iff it preserves limit, i.e. $\lim(x_n)=z$ in $X\ $ implies $\ \lim(f(x_n))=f(z)$.

So, for one direction we assume that $\ \Gamma_f:=\{(x,f(x))\,:\,x\in X\}\ $ is compact and that we have given a sequence $x_n\in X$ with $\lim(x_n)=z$, and we have to prove that $\exists\lim(f(x_n))=f(z)$.

For the other direction, we assume that $f$ is continuous and we have given an arbitrary sequence $g_n\in \Gamma_f$, and -- using that $X$ is compact -- we should select a convergent subsequence of $(g_n)$.

Answer (score 1):

$p:\Gamma\to\mathbb{R}$  is given by $p(x,f(x))=x$, is continuous bijection from graph $\Gamma$ to $\mathbb{R}$ so $p$ is Homeomorphism (assuming $\Gamma$ is compact), $\Gamma=\{(x,f(x)):x\in\mathbb{R}\}$

$p^{-1}:\mathbb{R}\to\Gamma$ is given by $p^{-1}(x)=(x,f(x))$

consider a map $q:\Gamma\to\mathbb{R}$, $q(x,f(x))=f(x)$

Now observe that $f=q\circ p^{-1}$ composition of two continuous function.